# Minimal cover of cartesian product of Sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

We have 2 sets: $A$= {$a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$} & $B$= {$b_1, b_2, ..., b_m$}
they both have sets of subets {$A_1, A_2,... A_{k_1}$} and {$B_1 ,B_2, B_{k_2}$}.We should find the approximation of the greedy algorithm for a minimal set cover described in  [Introduction to Algorithms](https://sd.blackball.lv/library/Introduction_to_Algorithms_Third_Edition_(2009).pdf) for the minimal cover of AxB = {axb | a$\in$A and b$\in$B} with the products of this subsets.
I used [this link](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Estevenha/cs4234/lectures/03a.SetCover.pdf) to understand the analysis of the algorithm better and came to the conclusion, that as described here, we will have O(log(m x n)) by using the same techniques.
Am I right about this?

And also if we are given the minimal covers of A and B can we incorporate this knowledge into this algorithm to make the approximation better?